# Export multiple output of queries in the same hive session to shell script?

Tags: unix, hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn

Is there a way to export the output of multiple hive queries in the hive CLI to the shell script?

Currently, I have shell script wherein there are multiple hive queries which I fire:

```
VAR1=`hive -e "select count(*) from table1;"`
VAR2=`hive -e "select count(*) from table2;"`
VAR3=`hive -e "select count(*) from table3;"`
```

This will run all the queries in a separate hive session which will cause it to wait for resources in yarn. Instead, I want to run them in the same hive session

```
`hive -e "select count(*) from table1;select count(*) from table2;select count(*) from table3;"`
```

and get the output passed to the shell script into VAR1, VAR2 & VAR3. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a sub query

```
select c1.*, c2.*, c3.* from 
(select count(*) from table1) c1, 
(select count(*) from table2) c2, 
(select count(*) from table3) c3;
```

Comment: I am thinking to make use of what has been mentioned in this link:

https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/151091/how-to-use-subquery-as-a-variable-in-hive.html

Some of my subqueries are complex, hence it would be better to break them down.